# Auto suggest/complete not loading in webdriver browser instances

Tags: testing, selenium, automation, webdriver

I'm having a little trouble nailing down what's causing a particular issue.  I'm fairly new to automation testing and I'm having a strange problem.  The website I'm testing has an auto suggest function which works absolutely fine when checking manually.  The problem is when loading a browser using the Selenium webdriver (I've tried firefox, chrome and IE drivers) that the auto suggest is simply not loading.

It's like the part of the page to do with that and a date/time mini popup aren't loading at all so none of them work when running scripts.  Has anyone else had this and resolved it? or is it an issue with the web page itself?

Thanks

Comment: When does the Auto suggest appear?  As you are typing?  When you hover over an element?

Comment: the Auto Suggest appears when typing into a field (usually around 3 characters) then continues to modify it's suggestions as more characters are typed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to fire an event which by default webdriver is not envoking with sendKeys.

Asking you developer how it works in their code, and then extend selenium to replicate this behaviour.

Also, have you tried do sendKeys one character at a time with a small sleep in-between

Comment: Thanks I'll give the sleeps a shot. I tried speaking to my developers but mostly got shrugs and confused looks followed by 'probably a problem with webdriver not loading java' :|.

Comment: Make the sleeps very small, say 500 mills, perhaps even less, but enough to be more human like.  The developers must be able to tell you what event the auto suggest is attached to, surely!!

Comment: I know it's calling from Google places but beyond that. There appears to be a great deal of legacy code created by people who are no longer with us.

Comment: If Robbie's answer doesn't work, you could also try Actions, or javascript commands.  However, I'm not quite sure why you are developing automation testing legacy code (that is quite independent of the rest of the site)